# Programmatically setting matplotlib plot to initial zoom level

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot which should view the entire set of data within the range `x = [-1,1]` and `y = [-1,1]`. When I'm plotting this in matplotlib, I can set this range with `xlim([-1,1])` and `ylim([-1,1])`. I can then play around with the plot, and if I wish, zoom in on certain features such that my viewing area is now displaying `x = [-0.5,0.5]` and `y = [-0.5,0.5]`. However, if I ever hit the home button on the toolbar, it will return me to the `xlim` and `ylim` default ranges.

What I'm looking to have happen is, I want to set the "default ranges" for the x and y limits such that the plot will return to those ranges when the home button is hit, BUT when the plot first appears, I want it to be zoomed in to the smaller range. That is, when the plot first comes up, I want to be looking at the range `x = [-0.5,0.5]` and `y = [-0.5,0.5]`, but hitting home returns me to `x = [-1,1]` and `y = [-1,1]`. Obviously I cannot use `xlim([-0.5,0.5])` and `ylim([-0.5,0.5])` to make the plot first appear that way as hitting the home button just sends me to the zoomed in version of the plot in that case.

Is there a way to do what I want? I don't see any documentation stating how to do this. If it matters, I'm using python 3.5 and matplotlib 1.5.1.